# Ejecutar archivo PHP con Crontab

Tags: php, crontab

Hola buenos días tengo un archivo .php llamado hola.php el cual obtiene la hora y fecha del servidor y lo imprime en un archivo .txt llamado example_crontab.txt. Programe una tarea en crontab para ejecutar el archivo .php a cada minuto, pero resulta que no se esta ejecutando el archivo hola.php porque me meti a ver el archiv example_crontab.txt y no esta la hora y fecha. Para asegurarme de que mi archivo hola.php no tenga errores de código ejecute con el comando php hola.php y si se plasmo la hora y fecha en el archivo example_crontab.txt llegando a la conclusión que no estoy programando bien mi tarea en crontab.

Podrían apoyarme a ver en que parte de mi programación en crotab esta mal. Les anexo mi código.

> Tarea programada en Crontab

```
* * * * * /var/www/html/php hola.php
```

> Código PHP

```
<?php
  $fh = fopen("example_crontab.txt", 'w') or die("Se produjo un error al crear el archivo");
  $hoy = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
  $texto = <<<_END
  $hoy
_END;

  fwrite($fh, $texto) or die("No se pudo escribir en el archivo");

  fclose($fh);

  echo "Se ha escrito sin problemas";
?>
```

Ejecute el comando ***php hola.php*** para validar que esté funcionando bien el código y si plasmo la hora y fecha en el archivo example_crontab.txt, pero con la tarea en crontab no se ejecuta el archivo .php

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Hola intenta esto.

```
***** /opt/alt/php73/usr/bin/php -q /home/**tuusuario**/public_html/hola.php
```

en servidor centos y php 7.3

claro también revisa la versión de tu php y especifica que servidor es , espero te sirva.

Comment: Hola aun sigue sin correr mi archivo php, el serviro que estoy utilizando es Ubuntu 14.04.3

Comment: recuerde poner la ruta raiz de su php

Comment: la ruta es correcta